# Progressbar disappears in battery saver mode (Android 5.x)?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, battery-saver

I noticed that when the Battery saver mode is enabled (by the user or automatically) in Android 5.x - ProgressBars in application just disappear.

No animation, no static progressbar widget - just empty place.

How to prevent that? I understand when Battery saver disables some system animations, but progressbars is actually an important part of the application UI.

Just in case - code that implements ProgressBar Layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/refresh_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/progress_bar_top_margin" />
```

And how it's implemented in my fragment class:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    // Progressbar to show refreshing state
    private ProgressBar mRefreshBar;
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);    
            ...
            // Initialize and locate Refreshing progress bar
            mRefreshBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.refresh_bar);
            ...
            mRefreshBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Also, I facing that problem with all progress bars in application, not only with this one.
When Battery saver mode disabled - all works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***When Battery saver mode is enabled, every app on the device have the same issue.***

Because Battery saver mode extends the battery life so that you can use the phone until you have a chance to charge it. It happens to every application. So don't worry.

> How to prevent that?

By disabling Battery saver mode in Settings and then rebooting the device. Or you can request [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) from the user to disable it.

Comment: Okay, I got it. But considering this, how to notify the user about something is loading? I have ListView with endless scroll (data loading automatically when users scrolls to the last item) and when there is no progressbar - looks like list just reached it's end.

Comment: you can use progress + text(Loading...) or something else. when Battery saver running user able to see text

Comment: you can also check gmail android app what they have done when Battery saver is on

Comment: I did it already, they did nothing - empty view is shown instead of progressbar.
Using text is great workaround. Also, I think, I still able to use gif animation for displaying infinite progressbar.

Answer (score 2):

> How to prevent that?

[ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) allows you to request the user to allow your app to ignore battery optimizations, I haven't tried it out, but it seems legit.