# Progress dialog showing circular arrow only in Android Oreo

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-8.0-oreo

On Android 8 - Oreo `ProgressDialog` not working, its just showing the circular arrow.

In my application

[image]

I know its deprecated in `API 26`

This behavior of `progress dialog` is same for Google's other apps

[image]
[image]

I have created custom dialog to show progress bar, is there any native solution for that

Device - Nexus 5x

Os - Android 8

Comment: Please show code

Comment: Progress dialog is deprecated in api 26

Comment: But what about googles other apps?

Comment: I have same problem on android oreo

Comment: I have seen same issue in YouTube app on Oreo as well HTC10 device.

Answer (score 12):

I just had the same issue with Galaxy S7 with Oreo and it did happen for any `ProgressBar`, not just in `ProgressDialog`.

Turned out I had turned off "Animator duration scale" in developer options. When I turn it on, I get the animated progress  bar again.

Answer (score 1):

`ProgressDialog` is **Deprecated** instead of it you can use `progressbar` if you want to use `progressbar` then the blow code is for you:

```
DelayedProgressDialog progressDialog = new DelayedProgressDialog();
progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

use [this](https://github.com/Q115/DelayedProgressDialog) Library

Comment: Does not answer the question and the person asking the question already stated that it is deprecated,

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue shows up only when battery is low. I found out that it's related to enabling Battery saver mode .
see answer here :[Progressbar disappears in battery saver mode (Android 5.x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221706/progressbar-disappears-in-battery-saver-mode-android-5-x)