# Android ProgressBar does not move

Tags: android, progress-bar

I add ProgressBar into my activity_main

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it should spin, but it doesn't. I do everything as in the official documentation,  what am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: I can see progressbar at top left .

Comment: I can see it too, but it doesn't spin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android this one you expected

Comment: I just want to see the rotation animation like in the answer below. This should work out of the box when adding a widget to the markup

Comment: I am getting this rotation animation while I tried your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770720/progress-dialog-showing-circular-arrow-only-in-android-oreo

Answer (score 0):

It's working!

[image: Here is the output!]

problem is not in the XML code

Comment: do you know what the problem might be? What version of android do you have?

Comment: Turned out I had turned off "Animator duration scale" in developer options. When I turn it on, I get the animated progress bar again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. You should enable all animations in the Developers Option on your phone. It will work.